# Thrown exception, but how to catch it properly in PHP?

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

My problem is that I have my own-defined exception in class' function in PHP which I'm able to catch, but it stops page from rendering at all in very interesting way.
Basically, when exception **is being catched**, page does not render. Instead of that it just gives me out string of exception what is absolutely different from my expectations.
I have this function which throws exception, which I do catch in child class' function because I do not use this class itself, just in child one.

```
    function auth($username, $password) { 
    if(!ssh2_auth_password($this->ssh, $username, $password)) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid credentials');
        return false; 
    }

    $fingerprint = ssh2_fingerprint($this->ssh, SSH2_FINGERPRINT_MD5 | SSH2_FINGERPRINT_HEX);

    if (!$fingerprint) {
        throw new Exception('No fingerprint');
        return false;
    }

    return $fingerprint; 
    }
```

*the exception being thrown is "Invalid credentials"*

Child class' function where this function being called

```
    try {
        $this->ssh->setupConnection($data['connectivity']['serverAdress'], $data['connectivity']['serverPort']);
        $fingerprint = $this->ssh->auth($data['connectivity']['serverLogin'], $data['connectivity']['serverPassword']);         
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->errorAndLog("blah blah blah");
        return false;
    }
```

*everything in child class inherited correctly and so on*

As you can see I'm catching the exception here, but page still does not render and showing up my exception in var_dump-like style:

> string(18) "Invalid credentials"

I'm not sure if I just do not figure out something about exceptions or the code is wrong at some point

UPD: I'm sorry, went bit wrong. Classes are not child-parent. The class with `auth()` function is being included into "main" one with

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->ssh = new SSH2();
}
```

Comment: `catch (Exception $e) { throw new Exception($e->getMessage()); }` or  `catch (Exception $e) { throw new Exception('blah blah blah'); }`?

Comment: @Hendra Nucleo What?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Just reworked code to work without throwing exceptions.